# Indentation of a lambda expression in C++

Tags: visual-studio

Here is what I have:

```
sources::range(0, 1000)
        .filter([](int val) {
                    return val < 200;
                });
```

Here is what I want:

```
sources::range(0, 1000)
        .filter([](int val) {
            return val < 200;
        });
```

Is there any auto formatting setting in a Visual Studio that allows me to properly indent lambdas?